# How do I remove third party tools from C++Builder 11?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-11-alexandria

In C++Builder 11.0, the JEDI tools are installed. If I go into Third Party, select Project JEDI, or any of its subheadings, it says 'please select and option on the left'. But, there are no options on the left other than the headings themselves.

The JEDI tool does not show up in the Windows App listing.

How do I remove this tool?

Answer (score 0):

You most probably installed JEDI from GetIt. So open the "GetIt Package Manager" from the *Tools* menu, select the "Installed" filter, select the JEDI package item (do not click on the header which is a link), click on the "Uninstall" button and follow the steps.

If you installed JEDI manually, then you have to find the JEDI sources on your computer. First uninstall JVCL then JCL. You have to run "install.bat" to uninstall either package.